# Error and flat notes

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

Lilypond gives me an error in the second line but I can't find out where it is.
Plus in the last line all the F note are flat (ff) but the second F note even if it is written correctely do not show the flat sign b, why?
Thank you.

here the exemple: http://lilybin.com/a000qh/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square bracket `[` indicating the stat of a beam group should be attached at the end of the first note in the group.

So the part:
. . . `\bar "||" [ff8 \melisma ef df]` . . .

should be changed to:
. . . `\bar "||" ff8[ \melisma ef df]` . . .

---

Some of the f-flats are not all showing up with flat symbol because LilyPond thinks that you are still in the same bar as a previous f-flat that is marked.

In music notation, an accidental symbol usually effects a note, and all preceding notes in that bar that are in the same staff position.

One option to get more accidental symbols is to use an exclamation point `!` directly after a pitch is given.

So the part:
. . . `ff16 [ef ff8] gf2 ff4 df8 ef ff2. \bar "|"` . . .

can be changed to:
. . . `ff16 [ef ff!8] gf2 ff!4 df8 ef ff2. \bar "|"` . . .

However, there are other ways to deal with this problem such as changing the time signature, or setting a different accidental style.